# ember-cli where to put images

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

In the ember-cli folder structure where should I put images?

```
/app
/bower_components
/config
/dist
/node_modules
/public
/tests
/vendor
```

I am using ember-cli version 1.13.1.

Comment: Check out [folder-layout](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#folder-layout)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Create a folder inside public -> `public/assets/images/`, and place your images inside. You can then access them in the browser using `/assets/images/imagename.png`

Source from the [ember-cli documentation](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#asset-compilation) it states:

Raw Assets

`public/assets` vs `app/styles`
To add images, fonts, or other assets, place them in the public/assets directory. For example, if you place `logo.png` in `public/assets/images`, you can reference it in templates with `assets/images/logo.png` or in stylesheets with `url('/assets/images/logo.png')`.

Comment: hey you are absolutely right. but i have a question how to add any java scripts  file to my projects.

Comment: @niteshsingh you can add it in vendor folder and give the path in ember-cli-buid.js file as follows
app.import('vendor/jquery-browser-mobile/jquery.browser.mobile.js');

Comment: To reference, I think you need `/images/{{model.story.id}}.png` and no more `/assets` these days. Just fought with this for 30 min.

Comment: For anyone trying to figure out why their images aren't loading on prod, make sure that you're considering the fingerprinting that ember puts on files such as images by default. https://ember-cli.com/asset-compilation